# Derivative of complex conjugate

Tags: calculus, derivatives, complex-numbers

In general, two different mathematical operations need not commute. Let f(x,y) be a complex valued function, taking in two real-valued inputs x and y. Then under what circumstances is the partial derivative of the complex conjugate of f with respect to x equal to the complex conjugate of the partial derivative of f with respect to x ? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always.

Let $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ with real functions $u$ and $v$. Then $f_x(x,y)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x,y)$. For the function
$$g(x,y):=\overline{f(x,y)}=u(x,y)-iv(x,y)$$
 we obtain
$$g_x(x,y)=u_x(x,y)-iv_x(x,y)=\overline{f_x(x,y)}\ .$$

Answer (score -1):

Only if $f$ is constant (in every connected component of its domain).

If $f$ is *not* constant, then $f(z)$ and $\overline{f(z)}$ cannot both have a derivative in the first place.

Comment: $f$ has a derivative with respect to $\partial_z$ iff $\bar{f}$ has derivative with respect to $\partial_\bar{z}$